# Is HDD RAW or NTFS?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I'm troubleshooting an internal HDD because of sporadic I/O errors (cables/SATA ports already checked out). Windows 10 recognizes the 3TB drive as being NTFS, so I run `chkntfs /C e:` to schedule a boot time scan.

Weird thing is, it wont query it. So I run `chkdsk /scan e:` and it returns that the HDD is RAW. That can't be right.

I run `wmic logicaldisk get,caption,filesystem` and it returns that e: is NTFS.

What gives? My end goal is to maintain the files in tact and either recover from RAW to NTFS and/or fix any bad sectors that exist.

Comment: RAW means it can't tell what the filesystem is, and if I/O errors occurred while it was trying to determine the type of filesystem, then you might also see RAW.  You should back up data immediately while you have some chance of getting the data.

Comment: I understand what each of the file systems are and I'm with you on the backups. I backup (full and partial) regularly using ASCOMP Backup. I ran a complete backup again ought away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy New Year, @Ian!

I'd advise you to back up the data from that drive somewhere else, before proceeding with the troubleshooting. The I/O error could be indicating a hardware failure as well. I'd not recommend you to run chkdsk, though. Instead, try using the HDD manufacturer's diagnostic tool or some other third-party HDD diagnostic utility to check up on the health and most importantly the drive's SMART status. The attributes will reveal if there are any bad sectors present.

Hope this was helpful. Keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks and to you as well. Thanks for the tip on chkdsk, I'll grab a third party shortly to run a diag on the drive and go from there. I've run TestDisk, chkdsk, and wmic on it and all reported back something different. Chkdsk and wmic are both Microsoft tools, so why would they report differently?

Comment: I've run SeaTools and Speccy. Speccy gave me a SMART warning while SeaTools failed the generic tests. Unfortunately, my backups include files that are corrupt, too.

Comment: It's recommended to use and trust the manufacturer's diagnostic tools due to the fact that they are specifically designed for that particular hardware product from the same brand, @Ian. Unfortunately, it does seem like your HDD is failing, so I'd strongly recommend you to backup any important data from it and contact the HDD manufacturer's customer support. Check if it's still under warranty, maybe you'd also be able to RMA it and get a replacement from them. Best of luck!

Comment: The Mfr software (SeaTools) failed and said to use SeaTools for DOS, which didn't detect the drive; so 3rd party was the only option. Thanks for everything.

Comment: In this case, I'd definitely consider replacing it. Don't forget that if it's still under warranty, you can send an RMA request to the manufacturer's customer support and get a replacement from them. Otherwise, you should look for a new one. Glad I was able to help you out even a little bit, @Ian! Best of luck! :)